# Force multiline typescript constructor in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm setting up some tslint rules, in order for my team and I to better adhere to our code contract. Is there any weay to use tslint, or vs code in general, to force the use of multiline contructors

eg

this

```
  constructor(
    private coreWebServices: CoreWebServices,
    private deviceDiscoveryService: DeviceDiscoveryService,
    private eventsService: EventsService,
    private log: LogService,
    private newsService: NewsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private runtimeService: RunTimeService
  ) {  }
```

in stead of this

```
constructor(private coreWebServices: CoreWebServices, private deviceDiscoveryService: DeviceDiscoveryService, private eventsService: EventsService, private log: LogService, private newsService: NewsService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private runtimeService: RunTimeService)
   { }
```

Comment: Use Intellij Webstorm. Muche more configurable and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) nor  [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) seem to have a rule you're looking for.

The closest one is [`align`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/align/) + `"parameters"`, but I don't see a way to configure it working with constructors only.

Comment: `align: "parameters"` doesn't break single line into multiple lines. It only aligns *existing* multiple lines with indentation so that all of them are on the same "column" (have same indent (spaces/tabs) from the left).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently there's a hack, if you add a comment after the line.

Source: My colleague and https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/352

Comment: You need to clarify that this requires the `Prettier` extension, and that the link only applies to **arrays**.